# Flexdashboard not loading when using Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have recently discovered the leaflet package and Flexdashboard and have no troubles using them separately.
However when I try to integrate a leaflet map into my Flexdashboard, nothing happens when I try to run my .Rmd
The viewer is stuck with the "Please wait..." screen...

I have tried to simplify everything, leaving nothing more than a few packages and a renderLeaflet line but it still won't load.

When using leaflet with shiny but without Flexdashboard I have no  loading problem. Neither when using Flexdashboard with other functions.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
  runtime: shiny 
---
```

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
```

```
Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
{r}
renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>%
                addTiles() %>%
                setView(lng = 2.342013, lat = 48.862871, zoom = 12)
              })
```

I don't get anything after waiting for a while, not even an error message.
Did I miss something? Is there an update that I should be looking for?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, your code is rendering both flexdashboard and leaflet in my R instance (After a couple of seconds). (R Version 3.6.0 Beta). Maybe try updating all of your packages and running in a fresh R instance?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end I just updated all my packages with

```
update.packages()
```

and everything works fine now !